# R Programming Time Series Decompose Failing

Tags: r

I am trying to decompose the stock data downloaded from Yahoo finance to see various components like seasonality, trend... but I am getting error  **time series has no or less than 2 periods**

Below is the code that I am using, Please help:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("IBM", from="2013-01-02", to="2014-12-31")
ibm = subset(IBM,select=c("IBM.Adjusted"))
write.table(ibm,"ibm.txt",row.names=F,sep="\t")
ibm2<-read.table("ibm.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
ibmtimeseries <- ts(ibm2, 
                     frequency=365, 
                     start=c(2013,1))

ibmtimeseriescomponents <- 
  decompose(ibmtimeseries)

ibmtimeseriescomponents <-
  decompose(ibmtimeseries)
```

> Error in decompose(googtimeseries) : 
>         **time series has no or less than 2 periods**

Comment: The error message says that there are less than 2 periods.  The code defines a period as a year and there are less than two years of data.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Actually I am new learner of R. Now I tried downloading data from jan 2013 to till date but still gettin same error.

Comment: Now I tried with full available data and it worked!

Comment: Note that it worked because it used years that are not leap years -- every period must have the same number of points so for leap years we will need to drop one day or allow the data to get out of sync with the year.

Comment: Thanks!!! Do you mean to say that if some leap year is in between we have to use some other logic? Before IBM, I was trying with Google and was trying to download data for 2013-14 but was not able to get the data. I was getting some HTTP error saying not able to connect to Yahoo.

Comment: Every period must have the same number of points.  There cannot be 366 points in one period and 365 in another.